# NLog do not logging on Database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, nlog

I can not logging on database using NLog. What is the problem? I am using ASP.NET Core 2.0 WebApi.

**On Startup.cs**

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddNLog();

        app.UseMvc();
        app.AddNLogWeb();

        var databaseTarget = new DatabaseTarget("DatabaseTarget");
        databaseTarget.CommandText = "insert into dbo.Log (Message) values (@Message)";
        databaseTarget.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        databaseTarget.ConnectionString = @"server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=CiPetPet;integrated security=true;";
        databaseTarget.DBProvider = "sqlserver";
        databaseTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@Message", "${message}"));

        LogManager.Configuration = new NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration();
        LogManager.Configuration.AddTarget("DatabaseTarget", databaseTarget);
        LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules.Add(new NLog.Config.LoggingRule("*", NLog.LogLevel.Trace, databaseTarget));

        InternalLogger.LogFile = "InternalLog.txt";
    }
```

**On Controller**

```
        [HttpGet]
    public string Index()
    {
        LogManager.EnableLogging();
        var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        logger.Debug("Debug log");
        logger.Error("Error log");
        logger.Fatal("Fatal log");
        logger.Info("Info log");
        logger.Warn("Warn log");

        return "Logging...";
    }
```

Internal log file is working fine. But database log is not work.

Comment: Remember to add nuget-package for SqlClient. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/2272

Comment: @Rolf, thanks for response. I have added SqlClient to my project. But nlog is not working expectedly.

Comment: You should not specify "DBProvider" in NetCore unless you specify a fully qualified class-name that includes assembly name. NetCore doesn't have any builtin DBProviders (NLog will by default use SqlClient if nothing specified, but it requires you have added the nuget-package)